# SymPy: Replace a symbol inside a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, symbols

I have a matrix that contains symbols:

```python
t = sympy.symbols("t")
A = sympy.Matrix([[np.exp(t),1,-1)], [0,t,0], [0,t+1,0]])
```

I want to replace all the symbols "t" with a number.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = sympy.Matrix([[sympy.exp(t),1,-1], [0,t,0], [0,t+1,0]]) # fixing your expression
print(A.subs(t, 5))
```

Which gives

```
Matrix([
[exp(5), 1, -1],
[     0, 5,  0],
[     0, 6,  0]])
```

Comment: Hmm your aswer works for this simple example, thank you. However my real code is a bit messy and more complex and maybe i will have to post another question.I have a matrix A in the power of k. MatPow(A,k) and when i sub the k with a number, the power stays outside of the matrix.Then when i try to multiply this matrix the final result is not evaluated, the results remains as (MatA^5)*MatB. But thank you for your time :)

Comment: @Emolai If you wanted to evaluate an expression, you'd do `A.subs(t, 5).evalf()`, or more compactly `A.evalf(subs={t: 5})`. Surprisingly, this will still not evaluate a `MatPow` object for some reason and I can't figure out why. Definitely worth a different question.

Comment: @Emolai Oh, try `sympy.MatPow(A, k).subs({t: 5, k: 2}).doit()`!

Comment: You aswered 2 questions in 1 :P